# Pointer to a pointer to an array (?)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Please forgive me if the title is not 100% correct. I have a function which takes two inputs - a pointer to a string, and a pointer to a pointer to an array (?). The function I am writing is
`int string_parser(char *inp, char **array_of_words[])`
What I want to be doing is taking these two arguments and the function should return

1. the amount of words in the string array (string array is `char *inp`)
2. a pointer to an array of pointers `char **array_of_words[]` - each element in the array pointing to the address of the first character in each word (I apologise if that is wordy)
   I have created the pointer to an array of pointers, and allocated space to this array
   `char **startOfWords_ptr = (char **) malloc(amountOfWords * sizeof(char*));`
   and have been manipulating the contents just fine. I now want to pass the array at `*start_of_words` back to `array_of_words` - but I don't understand how to do it

With `*array_of_words =  *(startOfWords_ptr);` am I saying: a pointer to point at the starting address of the array of pointers?
Surely I am not because I don't get the same values when printing...

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) *array_of_words); // 0x401f2c, o
printf("%p\n", (void *) *startOfWords_ptr); // 0x401f2c, o

printf("%p\n", (void *) array_of_words[1]); // 0x401f2c, o
printf("%p\n", (void *) startOfWords_ptr[1]); // 0x401f30, t
```

Suggestions with comments as output

```
*array_of_words =  (startOfWords_ptr); // This currently does not work

printf("%p, %c\n", (void *) array_of_words[0], *array_of_words[0]); // 0xcbbdd0, ;
printf("%p, %c\n", (void *) startOfWords_ptr[0], *startOfWords_ptr[0]); // 0x401f3b, o

printf("%p, %c\n", (void *) array_of_words[1], *array_of_words[1]); // 0x401f2c, o
printf("%p, %c\n", (void *) startOfWords_ptr[1], *startOfWords_ptr[1]); // 0x401f3f, t
```

Comment: In C++ one would normally use `std::string` and `std::vector` and avoid raw arrays and memory allocation. So no, not the same when using *natural* constructs of the language.

Comment: c++ tag removed

Comment: indexes start at 0. But that's not the only issue.

Comment: Jean, I don't believe that's an issue because `*array_of_words` is equivalent to `array_of_words[0]`

Comment: It is not clear whether you are trying to use `string_parser` or trying to write it.

Comment: You need to cast addresses to `(void *)` before printing them with `%p`.

Comment: @DavidBowling Thanks for your comment. Tried doing so but there was no change in output.

Comment: do you want `*array_of_words = startOfWords_ptr;` ?

Comment: I was not suggesting that missing casts are the problem, only commenting that you have UB without the cast.

Comment: @DavidBowling Acknowledged and noted.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for `*array_of_words = startOfWords_ptr;`.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input. I don't believe it's what I'm after - please see the body for output from `*array_of_words = startOfWords_ptr;`

Comment: `char **array_of_words[]` is an array of pointers to pointers to `char`.

Comment: @JohnBode Could you point out the obvious that I'm missing here? What is the solution to my problem?

Comment: @fOrceez: Let me make sure I understand your requirement - given an input string like "This is a test" (`inp`), you want to create an array of pointers to the first letter of each word?

Comment: @JohnBode That is correct- I currently have said array of pointers, `char **startOfWords_ptr = (char **) malloc(amountOfWords * sizeof(char*));` and I have the logic which points each element of the array of pointers to the first letter of each word. However, I need to pass this back to the parameter of the function (which I am struggling to do).

Comment: Thanks all for commenting. Turns out `array_of_words = startOfWords_ptr;` is definitely what I want and I was a silly goose with my dereferencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so let's look at this from the perspective of the caller of this function:

```
int main( void )
{
  char my_input[] = "This is a test";
  char **my_output = NULL;

  int count = string_parser( my_input, &my_output );
  for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    printf( "pointer #%d: %p\n", i, (void *) my_output[i] );
}
```

We know that after calling `string_parser`, `my_output` will point to the first of a sequence of pointers to `char`.  Since we need to modify the value of `my_output`, we must pass a pointer to it in the call (`&my_output`).

This means that the prototype for `string_parser` needs to be

```
int string_parser( const char *inp, char ***array_of_words ) 
{
   ...
}
```

In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are both treated as `T *a`, so `char ***array_of_words` is the same as `char **array_of_words[]` - both are ultimately `char ***`.

So given

> I have created the pointer to an array of pointers, and allocated space to this array
>   `char **startOfWords_ptr = (char **) malloc(amountOfWords * sizeof(char*));`
>   and have been manipulating the contents just fine. I now want to pass the array at `*start_of_words` back to `array_of_words` - but I don't understand how to do it

you have it  backwards - you'd assign the `startOfWords_ptr` to `*array_of_words`:

```
*array_of_words = startOfWords_ptr; // char ** = char **
```

`array_of_words` has one more level of indirection than `startOfWords_ptr`, so we need to dereference it to get the types to match.  After this assignment,

```
*array_of_words[i] == startOfWords_ptr[i] // char * == char *
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me get an understanding of what I needed. Turns out even when I had the correct assignment, I was printing incorrectly. Dereferencing when I didn't need to, not dereferencing when I needed to. Answer has been accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

this parameter in the function signature:

```
char **array_of_words[]
```

can be re-written as:

```
char ***array_of_words
```

I.E.  either write it as:

```
char **array_of_words
```

or as:

```
char *array_of_words[]
```

This is very similar to the different ways the second parameter to `main()` can be written.